# capturing the part after a special character along with a string in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have the following string:

```
$string = 'perl/abc.t wstat[0]';
```

I need to extract the portion abc.t from the string. I tried the following regex and got only the abc. portion in the variable $1.

```
 if ($string =~ qr{^.*perl\/(\S+)\S+}) {
    print Dumper $1;
}
```

This gives the $1 as 'abc.'
New to regex.

Answer (score 2):

You are declaring `\S` as two time it means it should match two non white space character (minimum possible match). So your regex can't considering the `.t` so your regex should be

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZPRNjN/3)

```
perl\/(\S+)\s+
```

or

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZPRNjN/5)

```
perl\/([^\s]+)
```

See this [debugger](https://regex101.com/r/ZPRNjN/1/debugger) 
 see the step `12` `13`.

For your first `\S+`, `abc.t` is matching (step 12).

Then you have mention another `\S+`. So your RegEx involving in [backtracking](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Backtracking) to match the another non white space character (step 13).

Answer (score 1):

Look at your input string:

```
'perl/abc.t wstat[0]';
           ▲
           └────────➔ That's a space
```

Your pattern is `^.*perl\/(\S+)\S+}`: That is, you want to find two spans of ***non***-space characters one after the other following `perl/` (BTW, you *probably* don't need to anchor the pattern if you are just going to look for "a span of any number of characters other than newline from the beginning").

The only way to greedily satisfy the requirement of *two* spans of non-space characters after `perl/` is to put the character sequence `abc.` (all non-space) in the first span, and put the last remaining character `t` in the second.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = 'perl/abc.t wstat[0]';

if ( $string =~ m{ perl/ (\S+) }x ) {
    print "Basename is '$1'\n";
}
```

`use re 'debug'` or `use re 'debugcolor'` to get more detailed information about the regexes in your program. In this case, note that:

```
Compiling REx " ^.* perl/ (\S+) "
Final program:
   1: SBOL /^/ (2)
   2: STAR (4)
   3:   REG_ANY (0)
   4: EXACT <perl/> (7)
   7: OPEN1 (9)
   9:   PLUS (11)
  10:     NPOSIXD[\s] (0)
  11: CLOSE1 (13)
  13: END (0)
```

and

```
Compiling REx " perl/ (\S+) "
Final program:
   1: EXACT <perl/> (4)
   4: OPEN1 (6)
   6:   PLUS (8)
   7:     NPOSIXD[\s] (0)
   8: CLOSE1 (10)
  10: END (0)
```

If that is too complicated, there is also [YAPE::Regex::Explain](https://metacpan.org/pod/YAPE::Regex::Explain):

```perl
C:\Temp> perl -MYAPE::Regex::Explain -e "print YAPE::Regex::Explain->new(qr{perl/(\S+)\S+})->explain"
```

```
The regular expression:

(?-imsx:perl/(\S+)\S+)

matches as follows:

NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
(?-imsx:                 group, but do not capture (case-sensitive)
                         (with ^ and $ matching normally) (with . not
                         matching \n) (matching whitespace and #
                         normally):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  perl/                    'perl/'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \S+                      non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f,
                             and " ") (1 or more times (matching the
                             most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \S+                      non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f,
                           and " ") (1 or more times (matching the
                           most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
)                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```